# I understand that the PIVOT command can transform a dataset, is this the correct way how to do it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
+----+-------------+
| ID | StoreVisit  |
+----+-------------+  
| 1  |  Home Depot |
| 2  |  Lowes      | 
| 3  |  Home Depot |
| 2  |  ACE        |
| 2  |  Lowes      |
| 1  |  Home Depot |
| 4  |  ACE        |
| 5  |  ACE        |
| 4  |  Lowes      |
+----+-------------+
```

I'm new(ish) to SQL and I know I can select all and then either use Excel (pivot table / functions / paste special) or R (tidyr) to transpose.. however, if I have a lot of data, this is not efficient. Is the query below correct? If so, how can I define all values of StoreVisit if there are thousands of types of stores without typing each one in the query?

```
select * from Stores
pivot (COUNT(StoreVisit) for StoreVisit in ([ACE],[Lowes],[Home Depot])) as StoreCounts

+----+-------+-----------+-----+
| ID | Lowes | HomeDepot | ACE |
+----+-------+-----------+-----+
| 1  |   0   |     2     |  0  |
| 2  |   2   |     0     |  0  |
| 3  |   0   |     1     |  0  |
| 4  |   1   |     0     |  1  |
| 5  |   0   |     0     |  1  |
+----+-------+-----------+-----+
```

Please excuse the formatting of this post! Many apologies.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       sum(storevisit = 'Lowes') as lowes,
       sum(storevisit = 'HomeDepot') as HomeDepot,
       sum(storevisit = 'Ace') as ace
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Is there a way to not define each column "as ..." using an assumption there could be hundreds of columns?

Comment: @DonJ . . . I don't think so.